# Change shader saturation gradually

Tags: texturing, uv, shaders, coordinates

I've stumbled upon a problem while working on a facade shader. I am pretty sure the solution is quite simple but I just cannot work it out myself. I would like to be able to control the saturation of a certain shader gradually - I am using a wood shader for facade and I want to achieve the worn wood effect - the top parts are still saturated while the lower parts are almost grey. Is there a way to somehow control this values using colour adjustments nodes? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be many other ways - I mixed the image texture with a desaturated version using a linear gradient node - hope this helps.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

this is a starting point (not 100% correct, but you can play with these nodes):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much for your quick replies @Justin @Sanbaldo! I could not make each of them work 100% but based on your ideas I came up with something like this and it works perfectly. Thanks so much. [image]